# Can you program a custom learning rate scheduler in Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I know the learning rate can be adjusted in Keras, but all the options seem to only include some decay or decreasing learning rate. I am wondering if it's possible to create a custom schedule that works like ReduceLROnPlateau, where it is looking to see if the loss stops decreasing for some number of epochs, and if so then it decreases the LR. But after some number of "decreases" it then increases the learning rate the next time loss stagnates, and then continues decreasing again on loss stagnation after that.

My thought here is that you may descend into a local minimum that you may not be able to escape from unless you increase the learning rate, before continuing to descend to the global minimum.

Does it make sense to create a function for learning rate? Would Keras accept that?

Can anyone give me an idea on how I would write that function?

Answer (score 2):

Keras has the [LearningRateScheduler](https://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler) callback which you can use to change the learning rate during training. But what you want sounds more like you need to get some information about the current loss value and/or the gradients, and for that you probably want to write an optimizer instead.

Comment: There is very little documentation regarding LearningRateScheduler, but it appears to only take the epoch number into account, not the loss. So while this could be useful, and I'll definitely try it, it isn't exactly what I was hoping for. I have no idea how to create an optimizer, but I'll look into that, too. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @KenWallace, actually, the function Matias describes can def. take loss into account. example here: https://www.kaggle.com/fergusoci/keras-loss-based-learning-rate-scheduler